# Unable to telnet to GCP MemoryStore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

I have created an instance of the Memory store in my project but I am unable to telnet / connect to it, either from my local or the Google Cloud Shell. Searching online, I see that other people have been granted the same host IP as mine so I am a little confused (10.0.0.3). Some assistance on how to proceed here would be great. Do I have to expose something here?

I have completed the following:

1. Recreated my VM on the same region as the memory store
2. Created a new instance of the memory store (gave me a new IP) but I am still unable to telnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to Cloud MemoryStore provided that you are in the same project, region and network. If any of these are different you will not be able to connect.

The IP address 10.0.0.3 is an RFC 1918 private address. This is why you must be in the same network to be able to connect. Also you need to enable firewall rules to allow traffic between your instance and Cloud Memorystore.

This link shows you how to connect to Cloud Memorystore from a GCE instance.

[Connecting to a Redis Instance](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance)

Comment: I was missing the firewall entry and was trying to connect from my local. Thanks!

Comment: is there a way to connect from outside the network? I could not even connect from the cloud shell

Comment: No, you cannot. Cloud Shell is not inside your VPC.