# cannot connect to Redis Instance in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-memorystore

I created an instance on GCP, but I am not able to access it.
This is similar to this one, but the proposed solution isn't working for me:
[Unable to telnet to GCP MemoryStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936287/unable-to-telnet-to-gcp-memorystore)

I have tried to telnet to it, I am in the same project and region, but apparently I need to be in the same network as it's a private ip, but what if you want to connect using the cloud shell? Also, how would an application running on my local machine access it? 
I also included a firewall rule to make sure incoming connections are allowed.

Comment: you can check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281492/accessing-gcp-memorystore-from-local-machines)

Answer (score 5):

- To connect a client to a Cloud Memorystore for Redis instance, the client and the instance must be located in the same region, in same project and in the same VPC network. Please check the [“Networking” document](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/networking) where you’ll have information on Basic network settings, limited and unsupported networks, network peering, IP address range.
- You can [connect to Redis from different GCP products](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance) like Compute Engine VM, Google Kubernetes Engine Cluster or Google Kubernetes Engine pod, but you can’t connect directly from the Cloud shell or from your local machine since they are not in your VPC network.

Answer (score 1):

It may also have to do with a missing peering connection to your network. Check in your console at https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/peering/ to see if the peering is set up properly.

Using terraform you can use the following docs: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/redis_instance.html